# Cant set up initial_channels in twitchio correctly

Tags: python, keyerror, twitch

Hi i am creating a bot for a twitch using module twitchio. I have a problem with initial_channels, don't know what i am doing wrong. Here is my code

```py
from twitchio.ext import commands

client_key = 'XXX'
oauth_key  = 'XXX'

class bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(irc_token=oauth_key, client_id=client_key, nick='MrShark', prefix='!',
                         initial_channels=["recogn1zzze"])

    async def event_ready(self):
        print(f'Ready | {self.nick}')

    async def event_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)
        await self.handle_commands(message)

    @commands.command(name='test')
    async def my_command(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.name}!')


bot = bot()
bot.run()
```

And here what i got

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<WebsocketConnection.join_action() done, defined at C:\Users\recog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twitchio\websocket.py:543> exception=KeyError('recogn1zzze')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\recog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twitchio\websocket.py", line 558, in join_action
    cache = self._channel_cache[channel]['channel']._users
KeyError: 'recogn1zzze'
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<WebsocketConnection.join_action() done, defined at C:\Users\recog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twitchio\websocket.py:543> exception=KeyError('recogn1zzze')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\recog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twitchio\websocket.py", line 558, in join_action
    cache = self._channel_cache[channel]['channel']._users
KeyError: 'recogn1zzze'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Channels must be prefixed with an octothorpe (#).

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        irc_token=oauth_key,
        client_id=client_key,
        nick='MrShark',
        prefix='!', 
        initial_channels=["#recogn1zzze"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The nick should be recogn1zzze as well.

Answer (score 0):

The nick and the initial_channels params are the same that your nickname example if you user is MrShark -> mrshark

`nick='mrshark', prefix='!', initial_channels=['mrshark']`